# Field required, but not always - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a possibility for a field to be required in one form, and in the other not? I have two different forms, different models, that have one field in common, and I want it to be required in the first one, and optional in the other.

Comment: Use [scenario](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-scenarios/)

Comment: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-scenarios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to add scenarios as constants to model instead of hardcoded strings, for example:

```
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[['email','password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE],
Another way is to describe it in scenarios() method:

public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['email', 'password'];

    return $scenarios;
}
```

That way you need to specify all safe attributes for each scenario for different actions.

Set scenario in the model

```
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_CREATE;
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username, email and password are all required in "register" scenario
        [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER],

        // username and password are required in "login" scenario
        [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN],
    ];
}
```